# mod-rewrite weird behaviour on rewriterule

Tags: mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/*.  /tags.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  /site.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

I wanted the last rule to be:

```
RewriteRule    ^site/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  /site.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

If I change the last rule, it does not work at all. I get a 404 not found.
I have no idea why it doesn't work, is the word 'site' a registered word or...?

Comment: Try debugging by putting `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` in your httpd.conf, then restarting the service. Afaik `site` is not a special word. With the debug line, you can trace what rewrites take place.

Comment: If you change the last rule to start with `site/`, then are you actually going to a URL like `http://yourdomain.com/site/page-name`? Does there happen to be a directory called "site"? Is the 404 you get returned by apache or by `site.php` saying that the page parameter you are passing into it is not found?

Comment: The redirect works on a localhost, but online it's a shared server so can't change httpd.conf. The webhost is godaddy, the 404 is apache not found error. There is no directory called "site". Maybe godaddy has some weird configs? I'll try to write them. 

("LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3" does not work on localhost, the apache won't start at all with that)